# May synagogues issue interest bearing bonds

Tags: halacha, synagogue, money, yoreh-deah, lending-interest-ribbis

According to Halacha, is it permissible for synagogues to issue  interest bearing bonds and sell it to its members to raise money or no? Would this be prohibited as ribbit, or since the synagogue and membership in it is publicly accessible and nobody owns it individually, is it Permissible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a machlokes between many poskim. Some say it is permitted and others disagree.

As a sampling, the [Tzafnas Paneach 2:184](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1966&st=&pgnum=231) says that borrowing from a bank, or any other entity that isn’t an individual, there is no issue with paying ribbis.

R’ Moshe Feinstein in [YD 2:62](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=90) at the end, says that it is permitted for them to borrow money and pay interest, but not to lend money and get paid interest.

Other poskim prohibit it both ways.

Comment: The answer may change if the interest in question is only prohibited rabbinically, since this is a charitable institution.

Comment: This should be better than a bank, which has shareholders - a shul might be more like hekdesh which iirc is certainly allowed

Comment: See Tur YD 160 and BY there

Comment: He also says that the Rashba is matir because it is considered as not having an owner, like R' Moshe says about a corporation. For Ribbis Drabbanan he has other heterim.